# Duplicate Telegram bot id with multiple docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, load-balancing, telegram-bot

I dockerized my Node.js server, which also handles my Telegram bot.
now, I'm not able to use my docker image more than once for the load balancer etc. without getting `duplicate telegram bot` error.

is there a way to fix it without extract the bot to different docker image?

The nginx handle the load balancing if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Docker assigns a random container id which is set as the hostname of the container, either unless you are using `--net=host` or manually overriding, which is available as an environment variable inside the container. During the start of your node.js application, you could read this environment variable (`HOSTNAME`) and use it as unique identifier for your scaled telegram bots.